# Is there any limit for asking questions?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, post-ban

I have a problem on asking a Question

**Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
    * Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account.**

I have asked 11 questions till now in StackOverflow...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can I do when getting "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the system will not accept questions from users who have a history of asking many low-voted questions. If you earn enough upvotes on your answers, the restriction will be lifted.

See [*Can we prevent some of the low-quality questions from entering our system?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system) and [Jeff's announcement there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system/60294#60294).

Comment: What do "many" and "low" word mean here? Can you measure this with numbers pls?

Comment: @SuzanCioc ["To avoid bypassing the filter its internal rules are a secret"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers).